# Updating variable value from dictionary and best practice

Tags: swift, variables, dictionary, logic

As I progress into my Swift education, the time as come for me to ask for help about best practice and code optimization.

My app has become more and more complex every day and the current situation is as follows: I started using dictionaries and arguments to use a single function that can process a lot of different variables depending on the situation, which seems to be better practice than using 5 different functions that will do the same thing only with different variables.

I now have two files as follows:

Main1.swift:

```
class Main1 {

    static var value1 : Int = 1

    func updateValue(_ value: String) {

        let dict : [String : Int] = ["value1": Main1.value1]

        let dict1 = dict[value]
        guard var value = dict1 else { return }

        value = value + 1 // <- trying to update `static var value1`'s value from 1 to 2 here
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Main2.swift:

```
class Main2 {

    func updateValue(_ value: String) {

        let dict : [String : Int] = ["value1": Main1.value1] // <- thinking `value1` would now be 2

        let dict1 = dict[value]
        guard var value = dict1 else { return }

        value = value + 1 // <- trying to get 3 here
        print(value)
    }
}
```

These classes are simplified versions of my code but the logic is the same: I am trying to use variables loaded from dictionaries and update their values to be used in another file and function:

```
Main1().updateValue("value1") //2
Main2().updateValue("value1") //2 <--- I need 3 here!
```

-> *What exactly am I trying to achieve here?*

**To update the reference (static var value1 : Int = 1) value while accessing it through the convenience of a dictionary** (or different method but you get the point about convenience).

In fact I am trying to do `Main1.value1 = Main1.value1 + 1` while accessing Main1.value1 through a dictionary, which is impossible because I am not accessing the reference here.

I know this can't work, I have 3 different copies of `value` here but I don't how to update the variable value without using another global variable... I need your help to find a better logic.

I am open to any suggestion or thinking. I am not asking for code solution (which would be great anyway) but I'd love to have my education re-centered a little bit, I am starting to lose myself learning all by myself and the frustration comes from that I don't know what to be looking for anymore.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to use some variables in a function, update them (change their value), then use their updated value for other calculations in another function (located in another file and class). Both functions take these variables as parameters.

Comment: Instead of saying "functions" and "variables", try telling more about what they are unless what you're developing is confidential. Also, your current code makes quite little sense to me. Try explaining it more.

Comment: Can't you just change `Main1.value1` directly?

Comment: You mean by not using a dictionary? My example was a simplified version of the logic but my real function has +10 variables inside multiples dictionaries, I need to be able to avoid using the single `static var variables` and have everything transit through a single object in the function. Maybe uploading my actual code would make more sense but I'm affraid to shock everyone by the mess

Comment: If you think your code is messy, clean it up first. Or are you not sure how to clean it up?

Comment: I think I did my best to simplify it as much as I could but I also think I'm missing a piece of the puzzle here

Comment: I updated the question with more precisions about what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS

As per the comments below, here's a potential solution:

```
class Main1 {

    static var dict: [String: Int] = ["value1": 1]

    func updateValue(_ key: String) {

        guard var value = dict[key] else { return }

        value = value + 1 
        print(value)

        dict[key] = value
    }
}
```

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

In **Swift**, `[String : Int]`, `String` and `Int` are [value types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type), as opposed to their Objective-C counterparts `NSDictionary`, `NSString` and `NSNumber`, which are [reference types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type).

This means that when you do `guard var value = dict1 else { return }`, `value` is now a copy of what the dictionary contained, not a reference to that piece of data inside the dictionary.

So when you do `value = value + 1` you're setting the new variables value, but not the contents of the dictionary.

Following your logic, you need to put `value` back into the dictionary, like this:

```
func updateValue(_ value: String) {
    var dict : [String : Int] = ["value1": Main1.value1] // <- Change this to a var

    let dict1 = dict[value]
    guard var intValue = dict1 else { return }

    intValue = intValue + 1 // <- trying to update `static var value1`'s value from 1 to 2 here
    print(intValue)

    dict[value] = intValue // <- ADD THIS
}
```

Comment: Wow would this mean that the `"Main1.value1"` `reference` would be changed? Would using `NSDictionary ` be a solution otherwise. In fact this is exactly what I am trying to do: updating the `reference value` while accessing it through the convenience of a dictionary! Thanks a lot Bell!

Comment: As I mentioned, `Main1.value1` is not a reference. It's a value. So it will indeed change, hence you need to set it to be a `var` instead of a `let` (a `let` being a constant, which, by definition cannot change). The cool part is that Swift changes the value and reassigns it to `Main1.value1` for you. No need to worry.

Comment: `print(Main1.value1)` still prints 1 after `dict[value] = intValue`. I am sure the value is changed inside the `dictionary` but I am trying to update the `static var value1 : Int = 1` to be used somewhere else. In fact I'm trying to do `Main1.value1 = Main1.value1 + 1` but while accessing `Main1.value1` through a dictionary, which is impossible because I am not accessing the reference here. How can I access the reference with a `dictionary` or `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: Considering the fact that `dict ` will disappear after the method returns, the function is a bit redundant. Any particular reason why you can't set the `static var value1` directly?

Comment: I get it, actually I am trying to apply this logic to a much bigger function that can take a dozen different values and update them upon condition. Updating `static var value1` would be a mess looking like this: `if ... == ... { value1 = ... } else if ... == ... { value2 = ... } else if ... == ... { value3 = ... } ` and so on.. I thought passing `value` in parameters with a dictionary would be better but this has complicated my situation quite a bit for now haha

Comment: Take a look at [Pattern Matching](https://www.raywenderlich.com/134844/pattern-matching-in-swift). It's pretty powerful in Swift and it seems to be a good fit for your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the link! This would mean forgetting about using a dictionary right?

Comment: In this particular case you're exposing, yes. Or you could have the dictionary be `static` and change the values there. I'll update the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: I'd love to see that `static dictionary` idea! Meanwhile I will try to pattern the `variables` I need to have updated into my function taking. This will be a mix. I won't give up and go back to the multi-function class and try to keep using `dictionaries` when I don 't have to change the values

Comment: Your updated answer is exactly what I needed Bell! Thank you very very much!